# Efficient way to list parquet file partitions in python

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I have a partitioned parquet file that I want to read each partition iteratively.

However, I want to get the list of partitions first.

In this example I would like to get the list `[1, 2]`:

```
myparquet.parquet
- /partition_col=1/file1
- /partition_col=2/file2
```

For that, I might use pandas:

```
pd.read_parquet("myparquet.parquet", columns=["partition_col"])["partition_col"].unique()
```

But that results in a slow and unefficient way as it is creating a huge dataset (as many rows as I have in the whole dataset, in the order of tens of millions) to just enumerate the partitions (just a hundred).

There should be a simpler and fast way to do this, similar to what you get in SQL with `SHOW PARTITIONS table`.

Answer (score 1):

Does the below help:

```
import os
path=r"C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\question7"
list_files=os.listdir(path)
files=[x.split('.')[1] for x in list_files if 'part' in x]
print(files)
```

The above outputs ['0', '1'] for me as I have 'part.0.parquet' and 'part.1.parquet' in my folder named question7. Once you have the list, you may use the below:

```
df_list=[]

for file in files:
    ab=pd.read_parquet(path + '/' + 'part.'+file+'.parquet')
    df_list.append(ab)
final_df=pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: Good one, I guess that looping over the filesystem is a solution, not so elegant but a practical one.

Answer (score 1):

Does pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.fragments have what you are looking for?

[pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.fragments](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.html#pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.fragments)

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
outputDir = 'c:/mydir'
fileName = 'mydf'
dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(f'{outputDir}/{fileName}/', use_legacy_dataset=False)

dataset.fragments

[<pyarrow.dataset.ParquetFileFragment path=c:/...>,
 <pyarrow.dataset.ParquetFileFragment path=c:/...>,
 <pyarrow.dataset.ParquetFileFragment path=c:/...>]
```

Comment: I would say `dataset.partitioning.dictionaries` is what I was looking for, thanks!